# Navbar disappear after I click the burger icon and resize the window (I dont want it to hide)

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, responsive

I am new to web design and am now facing the following problem:
My navbar disappears after I click the burger icon (click trigger in the menu then click it again to hide it), and resize the window (I don't want it to hide). Here is the page: https://www.ramezamr.com/navbar

How to recreate the problem:

1 - Open the link https://www.ramezamr.com/navbar

2 - Resize the window to reach a width under 700 px (the burger icon will show on the left and navigation will hide)

3 - Click the icon to trigger the hidden nav menu and click it again to hide it.

4 - Resize the window again with a width more than 700 px and you will notice that the navbar is not visible **(The problem here is that I want it to show the navbar once I maximize the window).**

Regards

Comment: Can you give us the code of the javascript please ?

Comment: Please provide your code so that we can help you.

Comment: I guess he wants us to use ctrl + U (view source) on the link he's given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how javascript works. You have to trigger `onresize` event in order to execute same chunk of code and check window width every time it changes. And your code will not work it user changes width suddenly passing through 700px, so it's better using `>=`. See it below:

```js
function navMenu() {
  x = document.getElementById('nav');

  if (x.style.display === 'block') {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  var w = window.innerWidth;

  if (w >= 700) {
    document.getElementById('nav').style.display ='block';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}


nav {
  background-color:#ff4d4d;
  width: 100%;
  position:fixed;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 11px 53px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 11px 53px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 3px 11px 53px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  border: 0.2px solid white;
}


 
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.drop li{
  float: none;
}

.drop {
  display: none;
}




li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff4d4d;
 display: block;
 width: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

a:hover {

 background-color: #ff1a1a;
}

.droplist:hover .drop {

 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 11px 53px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 11px 53px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 3px 11px 53px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);


}

.material-icons {
 cursor: pointer;
 padding:8px;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 



}
.burger {
 background-color: #ff4d4d;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1;
 
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {

 body {
  background-color: gray;
 }

 li {

 float: none;

 }

 li a {

 
 width: 100%;


 }

 .drop{
 
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
 }
 .droplist:hover .drop {

 display: block;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;


 }

 nav {
  display: none;
 }

 

}


@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {

 .burger {

  display: none;
 }

 nav{

  display: block;

 }
}
```

```html
 <body onresize="myFunction()"> 
 <div class="burger" onclick="navMenu()">
  <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
</div>
<nav id="nav">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li class="droplist"><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
   <ul class="drop">
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
</body>
```

And here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ox01nwct/11/).

Comment: Thanks it works now . Actually currently I'am reading about java script and I guess I did go through 'onresize' event yet .Anyway, thanks very much

Comment: `resize` and `scroll` are pretty useful while working with views. have nice times learning

Answer (score 0):

I look at your code and find this

```
document.getElementsById('nav').style.display ='block';
```

Replace it with a

```
document.getElementById('nav').style.display ='block';
```

It should work.

Comment: I have tried it , but unfortunately didnt work . Thanks for your help

Comment: @ramezamr style.css line number 138, please try with removing display:none.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the console saying that `document.getElementsById` is not a function. The problem here is that it should be element and not elements. So it should read:

```
document.getElementById('nav').style.display = 'block';
```

The reason for this is that IDs are unique, you cannot have more than one HTML element on the page with the same ID. Therefore `getElements..` is invalid.

I also spotted:

```
if (w = 700)
```

Here, in the if statement, you are actually assigning 700 to the variable `w` and it will always evaluate to true. It is not testing for equality. You probably wanted to do something like:

```
if (w >= 700)
```